# Why do I get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'argon2':

Tags: java, argon2-ffi

I am trying to use Argon2 to hash a password however I keep getting an UnsatifiedLinkError. I believe my pom.xml dependencies are correct but It seems like the library cannot be found.

I tried manually loading the library (System.loadLibrary) but that did not work either.

Has anyone run into this? I would greatly appreciate the help.

I am using Intellij on a Mac M1.

```
import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2;
import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory;

/* used for keystore*/
public class Argon {

    /**
     * This method calculates/returns an Argon2 hash from the users password
     *
     * @param iterations Total number of iterations
     * @param memory Memory usage in kibibytes
     * @param parallelism Number of threads used for hash computation
     * @param password User password
     * @return password hash
     */
    String getHash(int iterations, int memory, int parallelism, char[] password) {

        // Create a default instance of Argon2
        Argon2 argon2 = Argon2Factory.create();

        // Instantiate password hash String
        String passwordHash = "";

        // Generate the hash from the user's password.
        try {
            passwordHash = argon2.hash(iterations, memory, parallelism, password);
        } finally {
            // Wipe confidential data
            argon2.wipeArray(password);
        }

        return passwordHash;
    }

    /**
     * This method compares the hash of the correct password (From the Keystore) to the hash of a password entered by
     * the user. It verifies the password hash against the correct hash and returns a boolean result.
     *
     * @param keyStoreHash Hash of correct password from Keystore
     * @param password User entered password
     * @return Boolean result of the comparison.
     */
    boolean verifyPassword(String keyStoreHash, String password) {

        // Create a default instance of Argon2
        Argon2 argon2 = Argon2Factory.create();

        try {

            /** If the password hash matches the Argon2 hash, then return true,
            else,  return false. */

            if (argon2.verify(keyStoreHash, password.toCharArray())) {
                System.out.println("\n\nHash matches password.");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\n\nHash does NOT matches password.");
                return false;
            }
        } finally {
            // Wipe confidential data
            argon2.wipeArray(password.toCharArray());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Argon testArgon = new Argon();
        char[] pass = "test".toCharArray();

        System.out.println(testArgon.getHash(10,65536,1,pass));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I lied, It was the pom dependancy.

From this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.mkammerer</groupId>
            <artifactId>argon2-jvm-nolibs</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

To this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.mkammerer</groupId>
            <artifactId>argon2-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
```